# CockroachDB equivalent of RowVersion in SQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, cockroachdb

I'm trying to migrate my SQL db to CockroachDB.

SQL Server has the `RowVersion` datatype which my database uses, which will automatically be generated every time a record is created, and then automatically updated (incrementally by a random amount) every time the same record is updated.

I know that CockroachDB has the type `unique_rowid` which will automatically be generated every time a record is created, but when the same record is updated, it will not update the `unique_rowid`.   Thus, this is not an equivalent of `RowVersion` datatype.

Is there an equivalent for `RowVersion` in CockroachDB, and if not, is there a functionally equivalent way to do what I want to do in CockroachDB?

(As an aside, I know that while PostgreSQL, which also doesn't have `RowVersion` equivalent, can use triggers as a solution, CockroachDB doesn't support triggers).

### Edit

The aspect from rowVersion data type that is important to me is the automatic generation on create and automatic incrementation on update. I don't want to handle the incrementation logic manually in the code side whenever I update (I want the db to handle this). And I don't use it as a primary key.

Comment: You could add a unique identifier for a row and add a new row as new version, the unique identifier marks all rows that belong together and row_numer would give you version of the unique identifier.

Comment: You can define a column like this in your table :  version TIMESTAMP DEFAULT current_timestamp(), for information unique_rowid() is suitable for use as primary key like this  : id INT PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT unique_rowid()

Comment: I don't think there is an exact equivalent. This is an unusual feature in SQL Server. The closest thing I can think would be generating numbers with unique_unordered_id() and incrementing them on update. (This would be a terrible thing to do a primary key.) Which aspects of the rowversion data type are important to you? If you just want a modification counter, you can declare an integer column and increment it whenever you update.

Comment: The aspect from rowVersion data type that is important to me is the automate generation on create and automate incrementation on update.  I don't want to handle the incrementation logic manually in the code side whenever I update (I want the db to handle this).    And I don't use it as a primary key.

Comment: OK. I don't think there is a native solution for your design in CockroachDB in that case, at least not in the latest version released today, 23.1.7. This is probably another area where you'll have to change your application to get the behavior you want from CockroachDB. There are typically quite a few, even when migrating from vanilla Postgres.

Comment: You might also want to ask on the CockroachDB Slack if you haven't already. It's possible that they have a solution for this I'm not aware of, or that they'd be interested in adding one.

Answer (score 1):

While CockroachDB doesn't support triggers, it does support the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level which provides the highest level of isolation.

My idea here is to manually check whether the row in the destination table has been modified since it was last read from the source table. The operation would be put inside a transaction at the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level to avoid any concurrency related anomalies.

```sql
CREATE TABLE source_table (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name STRING,
    RowVersion DECIMAL DEFAULT unique_rowid()
);

CREATE TABLE destination_table (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name STRING,
    RowVersion DECIMAL DEFAULT unique_rowid()
);

INSERT INTO source_table (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'SourceName');
INSERT INTO destination_table (ID, Name) VALUES (1, 'DestinationName');


BEGIN;

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

-- Fetch the record from the source table
SELECT ID, Name, RowVersion INTO @sourceID, @sourceName, @sourceVersion FROM source_table WHERE ID = 1;

-- Fetch the corresponding record from the destination table
SELECT ID, Name, RowVersion INTO @destinationID, @destinationName, @destinationVersion FROM destination_table WHERE ID = 1;

-- Compare the versions. If the destination's RowVersion is less, it hasn't been updated since the last time we read from the source, so update it.

IF @destinationVersion < @sourceVersion THEN
    UPDATE destination_table 
    SET Name = @sourceName, RowVersion = unique_rowid() 
    WHERE ID = 1;
END IF;

COMMIT;
```

Since the changes are made in a transaction at the `SERIALIZABLE` isolation level, if another transaction modifies the row in the destination table between the time when you read it and when you try to update it, your transaction will be aborted and you'll get a serialization failure error. In that case, you would typically retry the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

In CockroachDB, there's no exact equivalent of `RowVersion`, but a `crdb_internal_mvcc_timestamp` column for each table, that is updated each time when a row is modified/inserted.

```sql
demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> CREATE TABLE t (x int);                                                   
CREATE TABLE

Time: 8ms total (execution 7ms / network 0ms)

demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> INSERT INTO t VALUES (1), (2), (3);                                        
INSERT 0 3

Time: 7ms total (execution 7ms / network 0ms)

demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> UPDATE t SET x = 4 WHERE x = 2;                                            
UPDATE 1

Time: 4ms total (execution 4ms / network 0ms)

demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> SELECT x,crdb_internal_mvcc_timestamp FROM t;                              
  x |  crdb_internal_mvcc_timestamp
----+---------------------------------
  1 | 1690821546183360000.0000000000
  4 | 1690821577521285000.0000000000
  3 | 1690821546183360000.0000000000
(3 rows)

demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> UPDATE t SET x = 5 WHERE x = 3;                                            
UPDATE 1

Time: 4ms total (execution 3ms / network 0ms)

demo@127.0.0.1:26257/demoapp/movr> SELECT x,crdb_internal_mvcc_timestamp FROM t;                              
  x |  crdb_internal_mvcc_timestamp
----+---------------------------------
  1 | 1690821546183360000.0000000000
  4 | 1690821577521285000.0000000000
  5 | 1690821770887231000.0000000000
(3 rows)
```

To get a more human-readable timestamp, you can also use the `crdb_internal.approximate_timestamp()` [builtin function](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/functions-and-operators#system-info-functions).

Comment: I have seen the crdb_internal columns, but this does not work for me since I'm going to be reading the column on the application-layer, it needs to be a publicly defined column so it can be mapped.   Also from the official documentation: "There are memory and latency costs associated with each table in crdb_internal. Accessing the tables in the schema can impact cluster stability and performance."  which is something I'm looking to avoid.